# Popup window keeps closing when typing in its text box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, react-hooks, expo

I have this app where, in the home screen, there is a button that triggers a popup screen where I can type some text. The issue is that whenever I put any kind of text in either of the two text boxes (AppTextInput), the screen rapidly closes and reopens with the text boxes empty.

[Prints of the screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqt2q.png)

This is the code of the home screen

```
import React from 'react'
// imports...

const { width } = Dimensions.get('screen');
const imgWidth = width - 40;
const cardWidth = width / 1.7;

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

  async function getNews() {
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://newsdata.io/api/1/news?apikey=pub_314863835828fecb905c17f3c4e3d8e9556b5&language=pt&full_content=1&image=1&category=politics,world,science'
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    const results = data.results;
    setArticles(results); 
  }
 
  useEffect(() => {
    getNews();

  }, []);
  const categories = ['Popular', 'Recomendado'];
  const [selectedCategoryIndex, setSelectedCategoryIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [activeCardIndex, setActiveCardIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const scrollX = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  const style = {
    header: {
      marginTop: 50,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      paddingHorizontal: 20,
    },
    categoryListContainer: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      gap: 10,
      marginHorizontal: 20,
      marginTop: 30,
    },
    categoryListText: {
      fontSize: 17,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    card: {
      height: 280,
      width: cardWidth,
      elevation: 15,
      marginRight: 20,
      borderRadius: 15,
    },
    cardImage: {
      height: 200,
      width: '100%',
      borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
      borderTopRightRadius: 15,
    },
    cardDetails: {
      height: 100,
      borderRadius: 15,
      backgroundColor: colors.bg_secondary,
      position: 'absolute',
      bottom: 0,
      padding: 20,
      width: '100%',
    },
    cardOverLay: {
      height: 280,
      backgroundColor: colors.bg,
      position: 'absolute',
      zIndex: 100,
      width: cardWidth,
      borderRadius: 15,
    },
    topHotelCard: {
      height: 145,
      width: 120,
      backgroundColor: colors.bg_secondary,
      elevation: 15,
      marginHorizontal: 10,
      borderRadius: 10,
    },
    topHotelCardImage: {
      height: 100,
      width: '100%',
      borderTopRightRadius: 10,
      borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
    },
  }

  const CategoryList = () => {
    return (
      <View style={style.categoryListContainer}>
        {categories.map((item, index) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            activeOpacity={0.8}
            onPress={() => setSelectedCategoryIndex(index)}>
            <View>
              <Text
                style={{
                  ...style.categoryListText,
                  color:
                    selectedCategoryIndex == index
                      ? colors.purple
                      : themeColors.grey,
                }}>
                {item}
              </Text>
              {selectedCategoryIndex == index && (
                <View
                  style={{
                    height: 3,
                    width: 30,
                    backgroundColor: colors.purple,
                    marginTop: 2,
                  }}
                />
              )}
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }

  const Card = ({ article, index, promptedText }) => {
    const inputRange = [
      (index - 1) * cardWidth,
      index * cardWidth,
      (index + 1) * cardWidth,
    ];
    const opacity = scrollX.interpolate({
      inputRange,
      outputRange: [0.7, 0, 0.7],
    });
    const scale = scrollX.interpolate({
      inputRange,
      outputRange: [0.8, 1, 0.8],
    });
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        disabled={activeCardIndex != index}
        activeOpacity={1}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Detail', article)}>
        <Animated.View style={{ ...style.card, transform: [{ scale }] }}>
          <Animated.View style={{ ...style.cardOverLay, opacity }} />

          <Image source={{ uri: article.image_url }} style={style.cardImage} />
          <View style={style.cardDetails}>
            <View
              style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
              <View>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 14, color: colors.text_main, width:150 }}
                numberOfLines={2} 
                ellipsizeMode="tail">
                {article.title.length > 35 ? `${article.title.substring(0, 35)}...` : article.title}
                </Text>
                {/* <Text style={{ color: colors.grey, fontSize: 10 }}>
                  {article.description}
                </Text> */}
              </View>
              <Icon name="favorite-border" size={22} color={colors.purple} />
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
                marginTop: 10,
              }}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: colors.grey }}>30 comentários</Text>
              </View>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: colors.grey }}>{article.source_id}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Animated.View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  const TopHotelCard = ({ article }) => {
    return (
      <View style={style.topHotelCard}>
        <Image style={style.topHotelCardImage} source={{ uri: article.image_url }} />
        <View style={{ paddingVertical: 5, paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 8, fontWeight: 'bold', color: colors.text_main }}
           numberOfLines={2} 
           ellipsizeMode="tail">
            {article.title}
          </Text>
          
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 6, color: colors.grey, marginTop:4 }}>{article.source_id}</Text>
          {/* <Text style={{ fontSize: 7, fontWeight: 'bold', color: colors.grey }}>
            {article.description}
          </Text> */}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.bg }}>
      <View style={style.header}>
        <View style={{ paddingBottom: 15 }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 25, fontWeight: 'bold', color: colors.text_main }}>Seu Resumo Diário,</Text>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 25, fontWeight: 'bold', color: colors.text_main }}>Feito Sob </Text>
            <Text
              style={{ fontSize: 25, fontWeight: 'bold', color: colors.purple }}>
              Medida
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <Icon name='favorite' marginTop={5} size={30} color={colors.grey} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Favorite')} />
      </View>
      <ScrollView showVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>

        <Image source={require('../assets/images/arte.jpg')} style={{ marginLeft: 20, borderRadius: 15, height: 180, width: imgWidth, flex: 1, resizeMode: 'cover' }} />

        <CategoryList />
        <View>
          <Animated.FlatList
            onMomentumScrollEnd={(e) => {
              setActiveCardIndex(
                Math.round(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / cardWidth),
              );
            }}
            onScroll={Animated.event(
              [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }],
              { useNativeDriver: true },
            )}
            horizontal
            data={articles}
            contentContainerStyle={{
              paddingVertical: 30,
              paddingLeft: 20,
              paddingRight: cardWidth / 2 - 40,
            }}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            renderItem={ ({ item, index }) => <Card article={item} index={index}/>}
            snapToInterval={cardWidth}
          />
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            marginHorizontal: 20,
          }}>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: colors.grey }}>
            Últimos vistos
          </Text>
          <Text style={{ color: colors.grey }}>Show all</Text>
        </View>
        <FlatList
          data={articles}
          horizontal
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            paddingLeft: 20,
            marginTop: 20,
            paddingBottom: 30,
          }}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <TopHotelCard article={item} />}
        />
        <View style={{ height: 65 }}></View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

And this is the code of the tab triggered by the "+" button:

```
//imports...


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


const CustomTabBarButton = ({children, onPress, buttonColor}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
            top: -30,
            justifyContent: 'center'
        }}
        onPress={onPress}
    >
        <View style={{
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            borderRadius: 35,
            backgroundColor: buttonColor,
        }}>
            {children}
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

const Tabs = () => {
    const {colors} = useTheme();

    const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);

    const styles = {

        modalBackGround: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
        },
        modalContainer: {
            width: '80%',
            backgroundColor: colors.bg_secondary,
            paddingHorizontal: 20,
            paddingVertical: 20,
            borderRadius: 15,
            elevation: 20,
        },
    }

    const ModalPoup = ({visible, children}) => {
        const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(visible);
        const scaleValue = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
        React.useEffect(() => {
            toggleModal();
        }, [visible]);
        const toggleModal = () => {
            if (visible) {
                setShowModal(true);
                Animated.spring(scaleValue, {
                    toValue: 1,
                    duration: 300,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }).start();
            } else {
                setTimeout(() => setShowModal(false), 200);
                Animated.timing(scaleValue, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration: 300,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }).start();
            }
        };
        return (
            <Modal transparent visible={showModal}>
                <View style={styles.modalBackGround}>
                    <Animated.View
                        style={[styles.modalContainer, {transform: [{scale: scaleValue}]}]}>
                        {children}
                    </Animated.View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        );
    };

    const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const [customText, setCustomText] = useState('')
    const handleTitleChange = useCallback((value) => {
        setTitle(value);
    }, []);

    const handleCustomTextChange = useCallback((value) => {
        setCustomText(value);
    }, []);
    const handleCustomText = () => {
        fetch('http://192.168.0.29:8080/text/save', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(customText)
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Erro no salvamento do texto!');
                }
            })
            .then(data => {
                const text = data.customText;
                console.log("Token: " + text);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }


    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Tab.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: false,
                    tabBarShowLabel: false,
                    tabBarStyle: {
                        position: 'absolute',
                        bottom: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        elevation: 0,
                        backgroundColor: colors.bg_secondary,
                        borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
                        borderTopRightRadius: 15,
                        height: 60,
                    },
                }}>
                <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                            <Ionicons name={'home-outline'} size={20} color={focused ? colors.purple : colors.grey}/>
                        </View>
                    )
                }}/>
                <Tab.Screen name="Find" component={FindScreen} options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                            <Ionicons name={'search-outline'} size={20} color={focused ? colors.purple : colors.grey}/>
                        </View>
                    )
                }}/>
                <Tab.Screen name="Post" component={PostScreen} options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                            <Ionicons name={'add-outline'} size={25} color={colors.grey2}/>
                        </View>
                    ),
                    tabBarButton: (props) => (
                        <CustomTabBarButton {...props} buttonColor={colors.purple} onPress={() => setVisible(true)}/>
                    )
                }}/>
                <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                            <Ionicons name={'person-outline'} size={20} color={focused ? colors.purple : colors.grey}/>
                        </View>
                    )
                }}/>
                <Tab.Screen name="Config" component={ConfigScreen} options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                            <Ionicons name={'settings-outline'} size={20}
                                      color={focused ? colors.purple : colors.grey}/>
                        </View>
                    )
                }}/>
            </Tab.Navigator>

            <ModalPoup visible={visible}>

                <View style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                    alignItems: "center",
                    width: '100%',
                    borderBottomWidth: 1,
                    paddingBottom: 10,
                    borderColor: colors.grey2
                }}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 500, color: colors.text_secondary}}>Adicione sua
                        noticia!</Text>
                    <Ionicons name={'close'} size={22} color={colors.purple} onPress={() => setVisible(false)}/>
                </View>

                <View style={{marginTop: 20}}>
                    <AppTextInput
                        placeholder="Titulo"
                        customStyles={{backgroundColor: colors.bg}}
                        onChangeText={handleTitleChange}
                    />
                    <AppTextInput
                        multiline
                        numberOfLines={4}
                        placeholder="Seu texto"
                        customStyles={{backgroundColor: colors.bg, textAlignVertical: "top", maxHeight: 150}}
                        onChangeText={handleCustomTextChange}
                    />
                    <LinearGradient style={{
                        borderRadius: 8,
                        height: 45,
                        display: 'flex',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        marginTop: 10
                    }}
                                    colors={['#f872ff', '#d76aff', '#b561fa', '#9457e7', '#744fd4']}
                                    start={{x: 1, y: 0}}
                                    end={{x: 0, y: 0}}>
                        <Text
                            style={{fontWeight: 600, fontSize: 18, color: '#F5F5F5'}}
                            onPress={() => {
                                handleCustomText();
                                setVisible(false);
                            }
                            }
                        >
                            Enviar
                        </Text>
                    </LinearGradient>
                </View>
            </ModalPoup>
        </View>
    )
}


export default Tabs;
```

This is my first time working with both JS and React, so it can be a pretty basic mistake. Thanks in advance!

I tried encapsulating the saving of the text on change by creating `handleTitleChange` and `handleCustomTextChange` functions with `useCallback`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You should move ModalPoup outside the function body, everytime you make a text change it rerender the Tabs component and redeclare the ModalPoup that causes an unmount and remount.

Comment: By moving ModalPoup (and its dependencies) outside the function, now I'm getting the error "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.". I tried moving the "useState" and "useRef" hooks outside "ModalPoup" but still the same error.

Comment: Can you show your code? I don't see how is this possible.

Comment: Sure!

https://pastebin.com/frXmBDbj

Comment: showModal and scaleValue should be within the ModalPoup, but are you suggesting it still throws an Invalid hook call error?

Comment: Yeah, I tried moving them out and in the ModalPoup but the error still appears either way. It's strange because they're the only two hook callings that I see.

Comment: Can you try moving the exact ModalPoup shown in the answer above outside the function body?

Comment: By moving that, it accuses the absence of "colors" and "styles" in the scope. When I then move the two as well, it starts the hook problem.

Comment: you should pass the styles in through component props like visible